# Split one XML file to multiple XML File with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML in one file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>
  <file> <!--File1.xml-->
    <content>content file 1</content>
  </file>
  <file> <!--File2.xml-->
    <content>content file 2</content>
  </file>
  <file> <!--File3.xml-->
    <content>content file 3</content>
  </file>
</document>
```

How do I write an XSLT to break it to multiple files like below

```
File1.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>
  <file>
    <content>content file 1</content>
  </file>
</document>

File2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>
  <file> 
    <content>content file 2</content>
  </file>
</document>
```

etc..

Thank you for help.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0? If so, you should be able to use "result-document". See http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/xsl-elements/result-document.html

Comment: I believe we can only use XSLT 1.0. :(

Comment: Do you actually have to use XSLT at all here? If you are using using .Net for the transformation, just load the XML into an XDocument, select all the **file** elements, iterate over them and output a file for each one.

Comment: Yes can do that also but it is the requirement for me to use XSLT because a file can contain more or less data depending on their requirement

Answer (score 2):

With XSL 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="document/file">
            <xsl:result-document href="file{position()}.xml">
                <document>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
                </document>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tested this using [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/), which supports XSLT 2.0, using the command below:

```
java -jar saxon9.jar -xsl:transform.xsl -s:input.xml
```

This command generates three files: `file1.xml`, `file2.xml` and `file3.xml`.

```
$ cat file1.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
   <file> <!--File1.xml-->
    <content>content file 1</content>
  </file>
</document>
```

Comment: How about in XSL 1.0, is it doable?

Comment: Because as much as possible we want to avoid using third party components. We are using .Net for the transformation. Thanks

Comment: Not in XSL 1.0. The other alternative is to use xml parsing in .Net. For example, use an xpath (/document/file) to get all the file elements and then iterate over them, writing each one out.