# How can an xml be splitted to multiple files and displayed in browser

Tags: java

I want an xml file to be splitted into some number as:
this [Split one XML file to multiple XML File with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381349/split-one-xml-file-to-multiple-xml-file-with-xslt)? But using java.Please Help.

Comment: What did you tired?Please post show code that you tried?

Comment: You can easily try this yourself by first using one of the provided API to read XML. The splitting will be quite simple once you can read it. But first, you need to try

Comment: I 've used DOM Parser.I could read the xml but,i want every tag in the xml to be added in other document object.Is that possible?