# Split one out-file into multiple xmls after n elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am using a 3rd party software to generate an XML-file. This software allows to use a post-processor in form of XSLT (2.0).

My output files are rather huge, often reaching multiple hundred MB and several million of lines. I want to chunk my output files and have 1 file after each (lets say 10 products) instead of all in one file.

I found a smiliar thread here: [Split one XML file to multiple XML File with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381349/split-one-xml-file-to-multiple-xml-file-with-xslt) but since I'm completly new to XSLT, I can't figure out on how to give a specific range at which the files will be splitted. I assume `xsl:for-each select="document/file">` from the given example is the expression where to look, but I'm not certain either.

A simple XML looks a bit like this:

```
<Products>
  <Product ID="123" UserType="ITEM">
    <Name>First Product</Name>
    <Values>
      <Value AttributeID="someAttribute">foo</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="AnotherAttribute">bar</Value>
    </Values>
  </Product>
  <Product ID="456" UserType="ITEM">
    <Name>Second Product</Name>
    <Values>
      <Value AttributeID="someAttribute">foo</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="AnotherAttribute">bar</Value>
    </Values>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

As mentioned above, there are multiple thousands of products and for the sake of a clean overview, I left out the nodes before and after the `<Products>`-node.

How can I split my one given output-file to N files, which are split after lets say 10 products?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65607158/3016153.

Comment: Is there a single `Products` elements with thousands of `Product` child nodes? As for other nodes you left out, are they supposed to appear in the various splitted documents or are they to be dropped?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, 1 `<Products>`-Node with several thousand `<Product>`-nodes within. The left out Nodes don't have to appear in the splitted files. Perfect would be, if every file starts and with ends with `<Products>`. That way, they could be imported regardless of which file comes first. To add to this: The left out nodes *do* have to appear in some file though (for example 1 file before products, 1 after, containing all other nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `Products` element is a child of the root element you could use e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="size" as="xs:integer" select="2"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::Products)">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(current-grouping-key()) and position() = 1">
          <xsl:result-document href="headers.xml">
            <Root>
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </Root>
          </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/Product" group-by="(position() - 1) idiv $size">
            <xsl:result-document href="chunk-{position()}.xml">
              <Products>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
              </Products>
            </xsl:result-document>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not(current-grouping-key()) and position() = last()">
          <xsl:result-document href="footers.xml">
            <Root>
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </Root>
          </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Looks promising, but doesn't yield an output yet. Our software claims that this isn't a valid stylesheet. in notepad++ however it seems to be okay, but still without an output. I'm still investigating where the error might be. Thanks so far in advance, Martin!

Comment: Well, you said you have XSLT 2 so I used XSLT 2, I don't know which software you use and whether it really supports XSLT 2; most people using Notepad++ or similar in the past found out they only had XSLT 1 support in that editor, as any XML/XSLT plugins use one of the twenty year old XSLT 1 processors like libxslt, Xalan, MSXML instead of moving to Saxon 9 or these days Saxon 10 or Saxon-JS 2 or Saxon-C for XSLT 2 or 3 support.

Comment: I can only judge from the given documentation from this software, which states, that XSLT 2.0 is supported. I'll keep you updated as soon as I found out more.

Comment: @DasSaffe, also note that the stylesheet creates no primary output, just the secondary files `headers.xml`, `chunk-n.xml` and `footers.xml`, some tools/editors might only try to render/display/show the primary output.

Comment: Was about to accept the answer anyway: Already adjusted the script a little bit (the output-files had no file-extension) and there is 1 line missing in the header + footer, which is stripped right now, but I think I can figure that out! Works like a charme! Thank you very much.